# Stone wall cracking.

Tags: cracking

Hi all.

I would like to know how to make a sound of a stone wall cracking?

If any one can give me some direction it will be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ice can work well for this, freeze two items together with lots of water and then pull them apart.  You can vary the objects from cloth soaked in water through to solid objects such as ceramic or plastic dishes.

Answer (score 3):

I've pitched down Chuck Russom's rock library and its worked well for such a thing - depends on how big you need it to sound.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, it depends on your situation. How big is the wall? Large stones or small? Cracking, as in stress? Or cracking, as in crumbling to the ground? What is causing it to crack?

Comment: The film is an animation. It is a stone wall that is cracking but without the sound of rubble and collapsing. The cracks just become bigger and bigger. 

Answer (score 1):

How about playing with some wood creaks and snaps and pitching them down an octave or two?
Try different layers etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try finding some sounds of cracking / breaking bones. Horror libraries are great for these. Add in some creaking and even some rubber stretching. Worked well for me in a similar type of clip.

Answer (score 1):

rice krispies sitting in a bowl of milk pitched down a little bit?

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on a short animation, there was a rock-solid floor cracking. On one rainy day while going home I've heard the perfect sound - it was water dribbling on concrete from a pipe placed about 1m above the sidewalk. Little cosmetics and worked great.